# Vaadin data Binder - ComboBox issues

Tags: vaadin, crud

Later Edit: I noticed that by returning one of the `options` in `ValueProvider`'s `apply` method leads to having the check mark present, but appears to show the previous select too. I.e. if the current and previous values are distinct, two check marks are shown.

I am having troubles with ComboBox binding. I cannot get the `com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder` properly select an option inside the combobox - i.e. tick the check mark in the dropdown.

My binder is a "generic", i.e. I am using it along with a Map, and I provide dynamic getters/setters for various map keys. So, consider `Binder<Map>`, while one of the properites inside the Map should be holding a `Person`'s id.

```
ComboBox<Person> combobox = new ComboBox<>("Person");
List<Person> options = fetchPersons();
combobox.setItems(options);

combobox.setItemLabelGenerator(new ItemLabelGenerator<Person>() {
    @Override
        public String apply(final Person p) {
            return p.getName();
        }
});

binder.bind(combobox, new ValueProvider<Map, Person>() {
    @Override
    public Person apply(final Map p) {
        return new Person((Long)p.get("id"), (String)p.get("name"));
    }
}, new Setter<Map, Person>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(final Map bean, final Person p) {
        bean.put("name", p.getName());
    }
});
```

Wondering what could I possibly do wrong...

Later edit: Adding a screenshot for the Status `ComboBox` which has a `String` for caption and `Integer` for value.

[image: Malfunction example]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are creating a new instance in your binding, which is not working. You probably have some other bean, (I say here `Bean`) where `Person` is a property. So you want to use `Binder` of type `Bean`, to bind `ComboBox` to the property, which is a `Person`. And then populate your form with the Bean by using e.g. `binder.readBean(bean)`. Btw. using Java 8 syntax makes your code much less verbose.

```
Bean bean = fetchBean();
Binder<Bean> binder = new Binder();
ComboBox<Person> combobox = new ComboBox<>("Person");
List<Person> options = fetchPersons();
combobox.setItems(options);

combobox.setItemLabelGenerator(Person::getName);

binder.forField(combobox).bind(Bean::getPerson, Bean::setPerson);
binder.readBean(bean);
```

Comment: I am actually using `com.vaadin.flow.component.crud.BinderCrudEditor`. My bean is a `Map`, as I am aiming to generate the form dynamically, based on each property's data type. E.g. Integer gives a IntegerField, LocalDateTime gives a DateTimePicker field etc. Agree on Java 8 syntax.

Comment: I have noticed that when having the debugger active, and delaying execution as I inspect, the entries get selected properly... Could we be looking at some bug, maybe?

Comment: if I do `combobox.focus(); combobox.blur();` inside the setItemLabelGenerator, then the check mark is finally being rendered properly! This indeed feels like a bug to me... I have even tried this with ComboBox<Integer >, for simplicity, and having the same issue.

Comment: Just wanting to add here to reference that `Select` is working as expected, as opposed to `ComboBox`.

Comment: There is a known limitation with that checkmark, the empty string does not apply, see https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1900 Is this your scenario?

Comment: That's not the case. In my case, the value is always numeric and non-null. I have even tried to make the combobox selection mandatory (via `setRequiredIndicatorVisible`), but still without luck. Quite sad that such basic functionality is not working out-of-the-box.

Comment: I have added this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UdCd.png screenshot so that you can see how it looks for a user status field.